# Mulitple SSL and Domains on IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl, domain

I have an existing web server that has been running multiple, related, domains all under 1 wildcard SSL certificate using host headers.

www.mydomain.com  *:443
test.mydomaim.com *:443

I have now introduced a completely new domain onto the same server, www.mydomain2.com, which requires its own SSL certificate. I know that I cannot associate 2 SSLs with the same IP address so I have specified individual addresses in the bindings...

www.mydomain.com  1.2.3.4:443
test.mydomain.com 1.2.3.4:443
www.mydomain2.com 1.2.3.5:443

Both the original domains work perfectly and the new domain works under http. HOWEVER, I cannot navigate to https://www.mydomain2.com as it tries to load the *.mydomain.com certificate. If I browse to https://1.2.3.5 the browser shows the correct certificate. I have also confirmed on www.dnswatch.info that www.mydomain2.com correctly resolves to 1.2.3.5

I'm not a network / server guru - can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Typical. This has now just magically corrected itself! I suspect it was an issue with propagating DNS records.